# CPU pipe A FIFO underrun

Tags: 16.04, dmesg

Looking at my `dmesg` output I see (among others) the following in red:

```
[   11.880554] kvm: disabled by bios
[   11.911578] kvm: disabled by bios
```

… and a little further down:

```
[ 4816.264697] [drm:intel_cpu_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* CPU pipe A FIFO underrun
[ 4816.266824] [drm:intel_set_pch_fifo_underrun_reporting [i915]] *ERROR* uncleared pch fifo underrun on pch transcoder A
[ 4816.266844] [drm:intel_pch_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* PCH transcoder A FIFO underrun
```

Should I be worried / take any action with regards to the above messages? The computer is a refurbished Lenovo T420 I just bought.